# XFCE: set up global file associations

Tags: linux, debian, file-association, xfce

I have many users using a Debian system through thin clients and I'm looking for a way to setup file associations globally for all the XFCE4 desktop environments.

Is there a way to setup the associations for Thunar or another file manager and the xfce desktop icons so that they are all the same accross all users?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do that system-wide you need to create `/usr/share/applications/mimeapps.list` as follows

```
[Default Applications]
application/pdf=evince.desktop
image/png=eog.desktop
```

Use `xdg-mime` to find out the mime-type of your files:

```
xdg-mime query filetype /etc/passwd
```

You can find available applications with `ls /usr/share/applications/*.desktop`

Answer (score 3):

Use [mimeopen](http://search.cpan.org/~michielb/File-MimeInfo-0.26/mimeopen) tool. It provides you nice options and the saved option is written to `~/.local/share/applications/defaults.list` so that your selected option is saved as default.

```
   mimeopen -d /path/to/myfile
```

Reference: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/default_applications